# How do I make pylint recognize twisted and ephem members?

Tags: python, twisted, pylint, pyephem

I very much like having pylint tell me if I'm using a non-existent member. However, my new project is using both twisted and the ephem modules, which seem to confuse pylint.

How can I get rid of these (incorrect) pylint warnings without either turning off E1101 in general, and without sprinkling warning removal comments around every relevant call?

```
E1101:  8,0: Module 'twisted.internet.reactor' has no 'run' member
E1101: 49,25:sunrise_next: Module 'ephem' has no 'Sun' member
E1101: 63,26:sunset_next: Module 'ephem' has no 'Sun' member
```

Comment: I would do here the same answer I've just done on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156240/nose-tools-and-pylint (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17162842/853679)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is to add a section like the following to your pylintrc with the problematic classes.

```
# List of classes names for which member attributes should not be checked
# (useful for classes with attributes dynamically set).
ignored-classes=SQLObject,twisted.internet.reactor,ephem
```