# Nose tools and pylint

Tags: python, testing, nose, pylint

What is the right way to use nose.tools and keep pylint happy?

The following code:

```
'''
This is a test
'''

import nose.tools
import nose.tools.trivial

nose.tools.assert_equal(1, 1)
nose.tools.assert_equals(1, 1)

nose.tools.trivial.assert_equal(1, 1)
nose.tools.trivial.assert_equals(1, 1)
```

Results in the following pylint errors:

```
$ pylint -i y -r n /tmp/aseq.py
************* Module aseq
E1101:  8,0: Module 'nose.tools' has no 'assert_equal' member
E1101:  9,0: Module 'nose.tools' has no 'assert_equals' member
E1101: 11,0: Module 'nose.tools.trivial' has no 'assert_equal' member
E1101: 12,0: Module 'nose.tools.trivial' has no 'assert_equals' member
```

Of course, one could disable E1101, is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of disabling E1101, you should put:

```
ignored-classes=nose.tools,nose.tools.trivial
```

in .pylintrc, under the `[TYPECHECK]` section.

As it stands in the [pylint doc](http://docs.pylint.org/features.html#id27), this option is "useful for classes with attributes dynamically set".

Comment: This sounds like it should work, but pylint is still throwing the same error. What am I missing? I'm using nosetests version 1.3.0.

Comment: I just try in a virtualenv with python=2.7.4, nose=1.3.0 and pylint=1.0.0, with the rcfile obtain by `pylint --generate-rcfile`: no more E1101 when i put the `ignored-classes` in rcfile. Can you try the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

`nose.tools.trivial` simply inspects `unittest.TestCase` class on the fly and makes all "public" methods starting from `assert` available from `nose.tools` or `nose.tools.trivial`:

nose/tools/__init__.py:

```
from nose.tools.nontrivial import *
from nose.tools.nontrivial import __all__ as nontrivial_all
from nose.tools.trivial import *
from nose.tools.trivial import __all__ as trivial_all

__all__ = trivial_all + nontrivial_all
```

nose/tools/trivial.py:

```
...

class Dummy(unittest.TestCase):
    def nop():
        pass
_t = Dummy('nop')

for at in [ at for at in dir(_t)
            if at.startswith('assert') and not '_' in at ]:
    pepd = pep8(at)
    vars()[pepd] = getattr(_t, at)
    __all__.append(pepd)

...
```

Pylint cannot handle this "hacky" behavior.

Consider using `nose.tools.eq_` instead of `assert_equal` and `assert_equals` (these methods are actually the same). Hope that helps.

Comment: This is good insight.  Although, it looks like, in `nose/tools/trivial.py` "pep8" versions of the unittest implementations of `assertEqual`/`assertEquals` are appended as `assert_equal`/`assert_equals` etc.  But `assertEqual` and `assertEquals` are not added. nose.tools provides it's own implementation of `eq_`, different from the implementations of unittest (although both are intended to be the same).

Comment: Sure, good point, I meant `assert_equal` and `assert_equals`. Yes, `eq_` works a bit differently than `assertEqual/assertEquals` methods of `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 1):

Pylint doesn't understand nose underlying magic. As suggested, solutions include disabling E1101 or ignoring related classes. But the best is to contribute to the [pylint-brain project](https://bitbucket.org/logilab/pylint-brain) by submitting there a simple description of the part of the API not grasped by Pylint. This should be pretty simple from the doc and example you'll find there.

Comment: hmm, that link seems to be dead.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but I need a pip install to use this in production. Any plans to release a version to pip?

Answer (score 0):

Using pylint 1.4.3 (with astroid 1.3.6, common 0.63.2, Python 2.7.10), the setting that has to be changed is `ignored-modules`, and not `ignored-classes`:

```
ignored-modules=nose.tools,nose.tools.trivial
```

Answer (score 0):

Or upgrade your astroid to 1.3.6, the nose problem was fixed: https://bitbucket.org/logilab/astroid/src/fdc592a3609ca7b882e12110d072a0e12f899338/astroid/brain/pynose.py?at=default